# how to manage branches of a project for several clients using git or bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I believe you understood already by reading the title of this post. For more explanation, Let say, I have an `ERP System` with both `Server Side` (Back end) and `Client Side` (Front end). Now If I have more than 20/30 clients of that ERP System, what will be the best approach to manage my code branches?

**Note: there might have many scenario. for example:**

> 1. 10 clients out of 20 clients would have same code and same settings.
> 2. 10 clients out of 20 clients would have same code but different settings.
> 3. 10 clients out of 20 clients would have different code and different settings

**Here we obviously can use**

> 1. Dev Branch
> 2. QA Branch
> 3. UAT Branch
> 4. Prod Branch

But what would the best approach to handle all 30 or more clients feature changes? I will be glad if you shared your experience here.

Comment: Lookup the term "feature toggle": [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+feature+toggle), [Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=feature+toggle), [`WikiPedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. but I am very disappointed to see that two world class master already voted to close this. Not sure why they voted it to close. SO is here for helping developers and I am asking some help here for this issue but they voted to close it. Truly Disappointed :(